# Client development approach when webservices are not finished yet

Tags: android, web-services

I'm developing an Android application which consumes REST services that are not finished yet. I´ve been looking for some tool that could mock this REST services, in order to don't get stucked, and I found SoapUI. I'm having problems to setup this tool and make the REST services visibles for my mobile device.

My question is if I´m following the right approach or there are other choices that could fit better.

Comment: Your question is a bit wide and I'm not sure It's going anywhere, but I can tell you that SOAP is not REST, these are different concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with SoapUI, but I thought it only made Soap calls, not mock them. But maybe I'm wrong?

Either way, I would recommend doing the following for mocking your REST service that isn't finished:

1. Make an interface that represents the REST service. In Java you'd have something like DataService.java as the interface and then you can create various implementations of it. Things like DataServiceRestImpl.java - which would be the live REST service once it's done.
2. Afer you've made the interface, go ahead and make a mocked version of it. DataServiceMockImpl.java. This way you can pass around the interface in your code and the implementation can change easily.

Once the real service is ready you just swap the implementation of the interface and everything still works fine.

(As a note, this will also help you do unit testing!)

Comment: Thanks! Actually it is possible to mock REST and SOAP web services with SoapUI but for my situation I think it's better your approach